# Regular rxpression to convert a camel case string into kebab case

Tags: javascript, regex, camelcasing

```
function hyphenate(str) {

  var replace = "-";
  str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[\s_\b]/g, replace);

  console.log(str);
  return str;
}

hyphenate("This Is Hyphenate"); // this-is-hyphenate
hyphenate("camelCaseString");   // camel-case-string
```

I am trying to get my code to produce the results of the second function call, but have not identified a pattern that can do this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `\b` in your `[\s_\b]` means a backspace character. Not sure you really need this.

**Updated answer using the lookbehind feature introduced in ECMAScript 2018**:

```js
const re = /[\W_]+|(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])/g;
const strs = ['camelCaseString','This      Is Hyphenate','This_Should_Hyphenate', '09Report'];
strs.forEach(str => 
  console.log( str.replace(re, "-").toLowerCase() )
);
```

The `[\W_]+|(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])` regex will match

- `[\W_]+` - any 1+ non-word and `_` chars
- `|` - or
- `(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])` - a location between a lowercase ASCII letter/digit and an uppercase ASCII letter.

**Old answer**

I'd use a bit different logic: add a hyphen before each capital letter inside a word, and then replace and turn lowercase:

```js
var re = /[\s_]+|([a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])/g; 
var str = 'camelCaseString<br/>This      Is Hyphenate<br/>This_Should_Hyphenate';
var result = str.replace(re, "$1-").toLowerCase();
document.body.innerHTML += result;
```

**Explanation:**

- `[\s_]+` - one or more whitespaces or underscores
- `|` - or...
- `([a-z0-9])` - (Group 1) a lowercase letter or digit (since `\B` would not let us match an uppercase letter after `_`, add `A-Z` if you want to add `-` before each uppercase letter)
- `(?=[A-Z])` - a test for an uppercase ASCII letter (that is not consumed since it `(?=[A-Z])` is a lookahead, a zero width assertion).

Comment: Sorry what I meant to say earlier was how would I handle formats that like this "This_Should_Hyphenate"

Comment: The problem with the `_` is that it is considered a word character. I added a fix.

Comment: Thank you very much. You gave me some good leads to check out to learn more about regular expression patterns. I appreciate it very much as I am trying to learn as much as I can. So essentially the lookahead ([a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z]) matches ([a-z0-9]) only if a capital letter follows after it? I hope I understand that logic correctly. The "$1-" Will place a hyphen after the match from the lookahead?

Comment: @brndng 1) Yes, only if there is an uppercase letter  immediately after. 2) `-` will be inserted after the *overall match* value and lookahead match value is not added to that value as its behavior is *non-consuming*, it does not add its match to the overall match value and does not advance the regex index.

Answer (score 2):

Try a lookahead before lowercasing:

```
function hyphenate(str) {
  return str.split(/[\s_\b]|(?=[A-Z])/).join('-').toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: This is a very elegant answer, I need to do some research on lookaheads.

Answer (score 1):

You can use capture groups to get the lowercase followed by the upper case letter, and then convert the whole string to lowercase:

```
str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g,"$1-$2").toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe overkill to your requirements, but hopefully this answer will help anyone who is trying to convert (almost) any string into kebab case:

```js
const convertStringToKebebCase = str => str && str
  .match(/[0-9]{1,}(?=\b)|[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]+|[0-9]|\b|_)|[A-Z]?[a-z]+|[A-Z]|[0-9]+/g)
  .map(x => x.toLowerCase())
  .join('-')
```

Here are the tests for the above function so you can work out how it behaves (I renamed the function to `toKebeb` just to make it easier to read here):

```
// Lowercase
expect(toKebeb('path')).toEqual('path')
expect(toKebeb('PATH')).toEqual('path')

// Spaces
expect(toKebeb('path route')).toEqual('path-route')
expect(toKebeb('path route 0')).toEqual('path-route-0')
expect(toKebeb('123 path 4 route 567')).toEqual('123-path-4-route-567')

// Kebab
expect(toKebeb('path-route')).toEqual('path-route')
expect(toKebeb('PATH-ROUTE')).toEqual('path-route')
expect(toKebeb('path-route0')).toEqual('path-route-0')
expect(toKebeb('path-route-0')).toEqual('path-route-0')
expect(toKebeb('123-path-4-route-567')).toEqual('123-path-4-route-567')
expect(toKebeb('123-path-4-route-567')).toEqual('123-path-4-route-567')

// Snake
expect(toKebeb('path_route')).toEqual('path-route')
expect(toKebeb('PATH_ROUTE')).toEqual('path-route')
expect(toKebeb('path_route0')).toEqual('path-route-0')
expect(toKebeb('path_route_0')).toEqual('path-route-0')
expect(toKebeb('123_path_4_route_567')).toEqual('123-path-4-route-567')
expect(toKebeb('123_path_4_route_567')).toEqual('123-path-4-route-567')

// Camel
expect(toKebeb('pathRoute')).toEqual('path-route')
expect(toKebeb('pathROUTE')).toEqual('path-route')
expect(toKebeb('pathRoute0')).toEqual('path-route-0')
expect(toKebeb('pathROUTE0')).toEqual('path-route-0')
expect(toKebeb('123path4Route567')).toEqual('123-path-4-route-567')
expect(toKebeb('123path4ROUTE567')).toEqual('123-path-4-route-567')
expect(toKebeb('pathRouteA')).toEqual('path-route-a')
expect(toKebeb('pathRouteABC')).toEqual('path-route-abc')
expect(toKebeb('pathIsARoute')).toEqual('path-is-a-route')

// Other
expect(toKebeb('path-route0')).toEqual('path-route-0')
expect(toKebeb('path-route123')).toEqual('path-route-123')
expect(toKebeb('path1route')).toEqual('path-1-route')
expect(toKebeb('path123route')).toEqual('path-123-route')
expect(toKebeb('123pathRoute')).toEqual('123-path-route')
expect(toKebeb('123PATHRoute')).toEqual('123-path-route')
expect(toKebeb('123pathROUTE')).toEqual('123-path-route')
```

I mentioned that this function converts *almost* any string, and that is because of the way numbers are handled may differ for each use case. For example, it would be perfectly reasonable to expect `3dPrinter` to return `3d-printer`. The regex can be tweaked to support this, but it raises other issues such as how to handle `3dPrinter12`, `my3dPrinter` or `se7en` (i.e. which number-string order combinations are respected). Supporting such rules would massively increase the number of tests required and there will always be exceptions.

To support the `3dPrinter` example, you could add `[0-9]{1,}[a-z]{1,}(?=[A-Z]+)|` to the start of the regex (after the "/"), but it would break some of the earlier rules.

To learn about how this regex works, checkout the pattern on [regexr](https://regexr.com/5i2uk).